# Kendo Pie chart set color according to percentage value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, pie-chart, kendo-chart

I want to implement a pie chart in Kendo UI. The chart should display filled colors according to the percentage value. For example, the value 100% should fill the whole wedge, 50% should fill half of the wedge. Something like this:

[image]

Please help if anybody has any idea about it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't meant for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as intended, we can help you with that.

Comment: I referred the example of pie chart given on kendo UI website and implemented a basic pie chart. In the console I found that the chart is a group of SVG elements and g tags with paths. I played with the offset values of gradient fill (these values are according to my data values) to achieve the result I needed. This is the chart result: https://imgur.com/uwegiln. But i made this with static values. I don't understand how can I pass the offset values dynamically to achieve the same. I need help regarding that.